# google mock - mock return value of a (free-standing) function called

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a function that I'm testing, **f1()**.

**f1()** calls **g1()** which can return a few different values.

How do I mock **g1()** so I can iterate through the different values it returns in order to test the paths inside **f1()**?

```
int f1()
{
    int res = g1();
    int ret = 0;
    switch(res):
    {
        case 0:
           // ret = something
        case 1:
           // ret = something else
        default:
           // ret = bad result
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can try `cmocka` tool to do the above mentioned use case.

Comment: Actually there is another way using google mock but I'll accept this.

Comment: @Adrian Can you please let me know how to do through Google mock? If possible please show me the snippet.